# how to show an object as a row of wpf datagrid and convert it back to be an object

Tags: wpf, datagrid, datatemplate

I have an object similar to

```
class Quote
{
    string Ticker {set; get; }
    string Rating {set; get;}
    People Sender {set; get;}
}
```

Peaple is defined as,

```
class People
{
    string Email {set; get;}
    int Age {set; get;}
    string Firm {set; get;}
}
```

I also have an ObservableCollection of Quote,

```
ObservableCollection <Quote> QuoteList;
```

Now I would like to display the QuoteList in a DataGrid, such that each row have the following 3 cells,
1. Quote.Ticker
2. Quote.Rating
3. Quote.Sender.Email

I also would like to, if I click each row, I can get the Quote object of that clicked row.
May I ask how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you bind your `DataGrid` to an `ItemsSource` of an `ObservableCollection<Quote>` each `DataGridRow` will be built with the `Quote` object as it's `DataContext` (data layer).

By default, a DataGrid will automatically generate a column for each property on the data item, so in your case it would generate a column for `Ticker`, `Rating`, and `Sender`.

You can either override that by setting `AutoGenerateColumns="False"` and defining your own `<DataGrid.Columns>`, which includes a column bound to `Sender.Email`

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Quotes}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Ticker"  Binding="{Binding Ticker}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Rating"  Binding="{Binding Rating}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Email"  Binding="{Binding Sender.Email}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

or you can use an implicit DataTemplate to tell WPF to draw the `Sender` object with a string containing the `Email` property

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Quotes}">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:People}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Email}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
</DataGrid>
```

Of the two, I'd pick the first one for your situation since you won't need to code anything extra for things like editing

As for getting the data object when the row is clicked, simply check out the `DataContext` of the row, or bind your `CommandParameter` to `"{Binding }"`

Comment: Hi, would you mind to show me a link on how to make columns as DataTemplate?

Comment: thanks, I have tried method 1, but when I `Quote quote = (Quote)MasterAllGrid.SelectedItem;` , the Sender in Quote is null, how to get the DataContext of the selected column?

Comment: @tesla1060 `DataGrid.SelectedItem` will return the data item that the Row is bound to, so if you bind your `DataGrid` to an `ObservableCollection<Quote>` it should return you a `Quote` object for the row you have selected. Can you verify that your `Quote` data item has the `Sender` set to something that is not null?

Comment: @tesla1060 No problem :) Also, if this post answered your question, please check the green check mark next to it to mark the answer as Accepted

Comment: thanks for the heads up, i dint know that, now I have checked all my previous questions, and that increased my reputation as well.